# how to use in monodb like that we can use sql .select count(*), count(distinct(name)) from tt in mysql

Tags: mongodb

I have already tried use studio 3t. It has a sql to mongo shell, but it just can change "select  distinct name  from xxx" like this.

Actually, I need it can return the count(*) all recored count, distinct name total count in once time;

Comment: Share the document structure and expected result.

Comment: such as this document:
{
        "name": "name2",
        "iUpdateTime": NumberInt(2019),
        "abc": 6229.72,
        "double_test": 6229.72,
},
{
        "name": "name2",
        "iUpdateTime": NumberInt(2019),
        "abc": 999.723,
        "double_test": 6229.72,
},
{
        "name": "name3",
        "iUpdateTime": NumberInt(2019),
        "abc": 999.723,
        "double_test": 6229.72
}

how to stat distinct name count,and total record count